# Missing FROM clause entry for table "product"

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sellstatus()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
BEGIN
    if products."sellStatus" = "Sold" then
            update auctions
            set "auctionStatus" = "End"
            where (products."id" = auctions."idProduct");
        end if;
END
$body$
language plpgsql

create trigger update_sellStatus_auctionStatus
after update on products
for each row
    execute procedure update_sellstatus()
```

ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "product"

I want to UPDATE column `auctions.auctionStatus = "End"` after `UPDATE` of column `products.sellStatus = "Sold"` where (products."id" = auctions."idProduct").

So I create a trigger but I got an error. It's make me can't UPDATE table products

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference a table like in a function. But as this is a trigger. [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) you can access the values of the update row using the `new` record:

Also: string constants need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL, double quotes are only needed for identifiers (and should be avoided like the plague).
`"Sold"` refers to a column, `'Sold'` is a character (string) value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sellstatus()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
BEGIN
  if new."sellStatus" = 'Sold' then
    update auctions
      set "auctionStatus" = 'End'
    where auctions."idProduct" = new."id";
  end if;
END
$body$
language plpgsql
```